# Minimal SQLite table view in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt

I have just started digging into PyQt5 in order to write a small GUI for editing a lexical database. Before I dig deeper into this, I would like to have feedback on the progress so far. Some particular points of note are listed below.

- I envision use cases where two windows of this type and a window of different type each show different portions of the underlying table, which is why I used the `QSortFilterProxyModel` instead of filtering directly in the database. For my production data, I have about 50000 rows × 10 columns, does that mean I should change that? [See this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40209123/1274613)
- The implementation details of what `FilterDialog` and `FilterModel` look like will change, but is the communication reasonable? I get data from a user input (here, the `QLineEdit` in FilterDialog) into the filter by reading the content of the input widget and writing an attribute of the FilterModel before telling everything that that model has changed, is this what I should do or should I do something else?
- I have never really done GUI programming before, so I don't know best practices on how to structure projects like this – and I'm sure I don't know many other things. How do I ensure that this project can grow into something maintainable?

The code is the following, it takes one command line argument which is the path to an SQLite 3 database with a table called “FormTable”.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class FilterDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.init_elements()

    def init_elements(self):
        cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)

        okButton = QPushButton("OK")
        okButton.setDefault(True)
        okButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(cancelButton)
        hbox.addWidget(okButton)

        self.regex = QLineEdit()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.regex)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setWindowTitle('Filter Column')


class FilterModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, filters):
        super().__init__()
        self.filters = filters

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, modelindex):
        for i, filter in enumerate(self.filters):
            if filter not in str(self.sourceModel().index(row, i).data()):
                return False
        return True


class WordListViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super().__init__()
        self.dbpath = path
        self.init_elements()

    def init_elements(self):
        exitAct = QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('exit'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)

        self.statusBar().showMessage(self.dbpath)

        self.init_table()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('FormTable viewer')

        self.show()

    def init_table(self):
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName(self.dbpath)
        if not db.open():
            raise Error("Could not open the database")

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self, db)
        self.model.setTable("FormTable")
        self.model.EditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()

        self.table = QTableView()
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.add_filter_functionality()
        self.table.show()

    def add_filter_functionality(self):
        def show_filter(logical_index):
            dialog = FilterDialog(self)
            if not dialog.exec_():
                return
            filter = dialog.regex.text()
            self.filters.filters[logical_index] = filter
            print(self.filters.filters)
            self.filters.modelReset.emit()

        self.filters = FilterModel([""] * self.model.columnCount())
        self.filters.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.table.setModel(self.filters)
        self.filters.modelReset.emit()

        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        header.sectionDoubleClicked.connect(show_filter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = WordListViewer(sys.argv[1])

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```